# Call MVC Controller from Windows task scheduler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, vbscript, c#-3.0, scheduled-tasks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC3 how to excute action method of controller using timer with interval of one hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101636/asp-net-mvc3-how-to-excute-action-method-of-controller-using-timer-with-interval)

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.  I have one special controller for job scheduler.  I need to call this controller every night at midnight from the Windows task scheduler (like calling a .bat file from windows task scheduler).

Somebody told me that this is possible using VB script.  We can call VB script from Windows task scheduler and VB script will call ASP.NET MVC controller.  But I do not know how to do this.

If anybody has any ideas, please share with us.

Comment: To clarify, do you need to simply execute the controller action method or do you need to make a web request so a running web application?

Comment: simply execute the controller action method or make web a request. my requirement is that any of mention above will execute from windows task schedule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send an HTTP request to your MVC application using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/somecontroller/someaction");
}
```

Comment: how to make this request using windows task scheduler ?

Comment: You write an application, for example console application and then configure the Windows Task Scheduler to run this application at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

i solved my problem using following method. please check, it may help somebody.

[Click Here to see details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101636/asp-net-mvc3-how-to-excute-action-method-of-controller-using-timer-with-interval)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

We use [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) for exactly this reason :)