# How to call a method at specific interval of time in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an web application in MVC 3 and C#.

I need run a method every 1 hour for an unlimited time. I would like to know how to implemented it.

Thansk.

Related

[Call MVC Controller from Windows task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083087/call-mvc-controller-from-windows-task-scheduler)

Comment: In order for your web application to run a task, you would typically define/set it up in your global.asax.  The problem however is that web applications typically recycle/go to sleep when not being used.  This would prevent your timed action from being executed continuously.  If you have access to the server, you would be better off using a windows service for this type of action

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). But please notice that [implementing recurring background tasks in ASP.NET applications](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) is a perilous task. Don't forget that IIS could recycle the application pool at any time and under some circumstances (period of inactivity on the site, CPU/Memory thresholds are reached, ...) bringing down all background tasks you might have started.

The correct way to do this is to implement it in another application. This could for example be a Windows Service or a simple Console Application scheduled to run at regular intervals with Windows Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov, could you point me out some resurce for Windows Service  or simple Console Application

Answer (score 4):

Darin is correct, however, if you had to do it in your app, here's how you would go about it:

In Global.asax.cs

```
    static void ScheduleTaskTrigger()
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("ScheduledTaskTrigger",
                              string.Empty, 
                              null, 
                              Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
                              TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), // Every 1 hour
                              CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, 
                              new CacheItemRemovedCallback(PerformScheduledTasks));
    } 

    static void PerformScheduledTasks(string key, Object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
    {
       //Your TODO

       ScheduleTaskTrigger();
    }

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          ScheduleTaskTrigger();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, use a Windows Service or a Scheduled Task instead

Answer (score -1):

Best thing to do is use Azure Functions. It was designed for exactly this problem. It's actually pretty good. You can run a scheduled task whenever you like using a timer trigger.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview